# failure to get fbOAuth in Rfacebook

Tags: r, facebook

I would like to get fbOAuth to access live-long access token using packages `Rfacebook`

I got `app_id` and `app_secret` from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps,) after registrated an app. 
It required me to `"Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: http://localhost:1410/"`

I am not sure where i should paste the link to. And got error when

```
> fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id, app_secret, extended_permissions = TRUE) 
Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: http://localhost:1410/ 
When done, press any key to continue...
Error in authorizer(authorize_url) : 
  httpuv package required to capture OAuth credentials.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried after installing and include library "httpuv" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to paste url (**`http://localhost:1410`/** ) in developer app settings

1. Click on add platform.
2. Choose website and paste
   **`http://localhost:1410`/** in URL link.

Include package "httpuv" and this [link](http://thinktostart.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/analyzing-facebook-with-r/) will probably help you out.

Comment: Hi @Aashu, i tried me <- getUsers("me", token=fb_oauth) as shown in your suggested link. but it gives:                     
Error in callAPI(query, token) : 
  (#12) username is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

Comment: @useR In versions v2.0 ,they come with some more security restriction so try out with some username instead of "me".

Comment: Hi @Aashu, i have changed me to my username. while it give error about json Error in fromJSON(rawToChar(url.data$content)) : unexpected character '<'

Answer (score 0):

you have package httpuv missing, download it via:
install.packages("httpuv")
then load it again.